# Go routine for processing files in a work flow. What am I missing?

Tags: go

I am building something to monitor a directory for file uploads.  Right now I am using a for {} loop to continuously read the directory for testing purposes with the plan to use cron or something in the future to launch my application.

The goal is to monitor an upload directory, ensure files have finished copying, then move the files to another directory for processing.  The files themselves range from 15GB to about 50GB and we will be receiving hundreds daily.

This is my first foray into go routines.  I am not sure if I am completely misunderstanding go routines, channels and wait groups or something but I had thought that as I loop through a list of files, each file gets processed by a go routine function independently.  However when I run the below code it grabs a file but only acknowledges the first file it finds in the directory.  I noticed though once the first file finishes other files are acknowledged as completed.

```
package main

import (
        "flag"
        "fmt"
        "io/ioutil"
        "log"
        "os"
        "sync"
        "time"

        "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

type Config struct {
        LogFileName  string `yaml:"logfilename"`
        LogFilePath  string `yaml:"logfilepath"`
        UploadRoot   string `yaml:"upload_root"`
        TPUploadTool string `yaml:"tp_upload_tool"`
}

var wg sync.WaitGroup

const WORKERS = 5

func getConfig(fileName string) (*Config, error) {
        conf := &Config{}
        yamlFile, err := os.Open(fileName)
        if err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("Error reading YAML file: %s\n", err)
                os.Exit(1)
        }

        defer yamlFile.Close()
        yaml_decoder := yaml.NewDecoder(yamlFile)

        if err := yaml_decoder.Decode(conf); err != nil {
                return nil, err
        }
        return conf, err
}

func getFileData(fileToUpload string, fileStatus chan string) {
        var newSize int64
        var currentSize int64

        currentSize = 0
        newSize = 0
        fmt.Printf("Uploading: %s\n", fileToUpload)
        fileDone := false
        for !fileDone {
                fileToUploadStat, _ := os.Stat(fileToUpload)
                currentSize = fileToUploadStat.Size()
                //fmt.Printf("%s current size is: %d\n", fileToUpload, currentSize)
                //fmt.Println("New size ", newSize)
                if currentSize != 0 {
                        if currentSize > newSize {
                                newSize = currentSize
                        } else if newSize == currentSize {
                                fileStatus <- "Done"
                                fileDone = true
                                wg.Done()
                        }
                }
                time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        }

}

func sendToCDS() {
        fmt.Println("Sending To CDS")
}

func main() {

        fileStatus := make(chan string)
        configFileName := flag.String("config", "", "YAML configuration file.\n")
        flag.Parse()

        if *configFileName == "" {
                flag.PrintDefaults()
                os.Exit(1)
        }

        UploaderConfig, err := getConfig(*configFileName)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal("Error reading configuration file.")
        }

        for {
                fmt.Print("Checking for new files..")
                uploadFiles, err := ioutil.ReadDir(UploaderConfig.UploadRoot)
                if err != nil {
                        log.Fatal(err)
                }
                if len(uploadFiles) == 0 {
                        fmt.Println("..no files to transfer.\n")
                }
                for _, uploadFile := range uploadFiles {
                        wg.Add(1)
                        fmt.Println("...adding", uploadFile.Name())
                        if err != nil {
                                log.Fatalln("Unable to read file information.")
                        }
                        ff := UploaderConfig.UploadRoot + "/" + uploadFile.Name()

                        go getFileData(ff, fileStatus)
                        status := <-fileStatus

                        if status == "Done" {
                                fmt.Printf("%s is done.\n", uploadFile.Name())
                                os.Remove(ff)
                        }
                }
                wg.Wait()
        }
}
```

I had thought about using channels for a thread safe queueing mechanism that loads up with the files in the directory and then the files get picked up by workers.  I have done similar things in Python.

Comment: I think there is no need to use channel, wait group is enough.

Comment: Yea, I saw different examples of people doing something similar to what I am trying to do using channels as a work/job queue.  I was not sure if wait groups would accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the following lines, the code is processing each file sequentially:

```
go getFileData(ff, fileStatus)
status := <-fileStatus
```

The first line creates a goroutine, but the second line waits until that goroutine finishes its work.

If you want to process files in parallel, then you can use a worker pool pattern.

```
jobs:=make(chan string)
done:=make(chan struct{})
for i:=0;i<nWorkers;i++ {
   go workerFunc(jobs,done)
}
```

The `jobs` channel will be used to send newly discovered files to workers. When you discover a new file, you can simply:

```
jobs <- fileName
```

and the worker should process the file, and it should go back to reading from the channel. So it should look like:

```
func worker(ch chan string,done chan struct{}) {
   defer func() {
      done<-struct{}{} // Notify that this goroutine is completed
   }()
   for inputFile:=range ch {
       // process inputFile
   }
}
```

When everything is done, you can terminate the program by waiting for all the goroutines to complete:

```
close(jobs)
for i:=0;i<nWorkers;i++ {
   <-done
}
```

Comment: This is what I was originally going for.  Would a wait group be a better choice?

Comment: A waitgroup would replace the done channel. The two schemes are functionally equivalent.